# Worksheet_Change event executing on workbook open? Can I disable this behaviour?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'When we change the design range cell the sub design range cell is updated
    If Target.Address = Range("design_range").Address Then
        Range("sub_design_range").Value = Range("sub_design_ranges")
    End If
End Sub
```

I hadn't noticed this before, but every time I open the workbook this is executed, which changes the value in the named cell `sub_design_range`. I had thought this should only execute when I change the value in the cell `design_range`. Is there a way to stop this executing when I open the workbook and only execute when the referenced cell is changed?

Many thanks.

Edit:

If I open the workbook in safe mode this doesn't happen. I have disabled all add ins. It is not caused by external links as I have removed them all. What's strange is that the problem is intermittent: sometimes it doesn't update and sometimes it does.

This is the order of what happens when I open the file:

1. It asks if I can trust the file
2. It asks if I want to run macros / VBA code
3. The spreadsheet appears to populate with data i.e. the cells are filled with data
4. The macro executes and the cell is changed, when it shouldn't

Comment: I have edited my question to provide more information which may be the possible cause. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Is there any code in `Workbook_Open()` or `Auto_Open()`?

Comment: "I linked cells in the workbook to other cells from other workbooks" - using formulas, or some other way?  Calculating a formula doesn't trigger the `Change` event.

Comment: @taller there is no code there

Comment: @TimWilliams I have checked and the issue is not happening because of external links

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by adding a Worksheet_SelectionChange event. If the variable obtained from this event is blank then the Worksheet_Change event won't execute. This is probably not a very elegant solution but it works. Code below.

```
Dim oldValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldValue = Worksheets("design properties").Range("design_range").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(oldValue) = True Then
        If Target.Address = Range("design_range").Address Then
            Range("sub_design_range").Value = Range("sub_design_ranges")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```