# Prevent VBA code from executing on start up, but enable after data has loaded and been calculated?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem which I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78027826/worksheet-change-event-executing-on-workbook-open-can-i-disable-this-behaviour) that unfortunately I couldn't find an answer for. I have the following VBA code which is unexpectedly executing when the workbook is opened.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'When we change the design range cell the sub design range cell is updated
    If Target.Address = Range("design_range").Address Then
        Range("sub_design_range").Value = Range("sub_design_ranges")
    End If
End Sub
```

If I open the workbook in safe mode this doesn't happen. I have disabled all add ins. It is not caused by external links as I have removed them all. What's strange is that the problem is intermittent: sometimes it doesn't update and sometimes it does.

This is the order of what happens when I open the file:

1. It asks if I can trust the file
2. It asks if I want to run macros / VBA code
3. The spreadsheet appears to populate with data i.e. the cells are filled with data
4. The macro executes and the cell is changed, when it shouldn't

Either way, I'm hoping there is a way to disable this code from executing on start up until the workbook has updated all the data inside and finished calculating.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is causing this behavior on worksheet open: "The spreadsheet appears to populate with data i.e. the cells are filled with data"?